# mapView.annotations.count is not 0 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func countAnnotations(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Annotations Count = \(mapView.annotations.count)")

    if mapView.annotations.count == 0 {
        print("No annotations")
    }else{
        print("1 or more annotations")
    }
}
```

This is meant to check how many annotations are on my map view.

The issue arises when I start retrieving the user location using the following code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //Update the current location
    currentLocation = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(currentLocation.latitude) \(currentLocation.longitude)")
}
```

For some reason this seems to count as an annotation. How do I actually detect if an actual annotation is placed?

Comment: Do you want to show user location or it should be hidden?

Comment: I want user location to always be visible when possible.

Comment: Bump?  Still need some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by simply adding a `currentLocationVisible = false` bool variable. Then setting it and checking it.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      //Update the current location
      currentLocation = manager.location!.coordinate
      print("locations = \(currentLocation.latitude) \(currentLocation.longitude)")
      currentLocationVisible = true
}
```

Now its simply about checking the variable.

```
if (mapView.annotations.count == 0 || currentLocationVisible == true)
```

Easy as that!